# Jquery: Removing href attribute of parent list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, list

I have a menu consisting of a couplde of `<ul>`s nested within a couple of `<li>`s. eg:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="somewhere.html">Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="somewhere.html">Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="somewhere.html">Item 3</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="somewhere.html">Sub Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="somewhere.html">Sub Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

For the `<li>`s with nested `<ul>`s I want to replace their `href` attributes with #, eg:

```
<li><a href="somewhere.html">Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="somewhere.html">Sub Item 1</a></li>
```

I have written this script to do that, but it seems to affect all a tags within both lists.

```
$.each($("#menu ul li"), function() {
  if($(this).has("ul")){
   $(this).find("a").attr("href", "#");
  };
});
```

Was wondering if some one could tell me where Ive gone wrong?

Comment: `;` at the end of `if`.

Comment: @Jai good spotting but im afraid it doesnt change anything

Comment: @Jai That doesn't matter...

Comment: @MeltingDog Take a look at the demo I added to my answer. The answer you accepted doesn't work (and is also a more inefficient and verbose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for dom if its have child like below.

```
$(this).children('ul').length
```

In your code its inside if conditions where you are checking using `.has`

**Tested Working Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function()
    {
        $.each($("#menu ul li"), function()
        {
            if($(this).children('ul').length > 0)
            {
                $(this).find("a").attr("href", "#");
            };
        });
    });

</script>

<ul>
    <li><a href="somewhere.html">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="somewhere.html">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="somewhere.html">Item 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="somewhere.html">Sub Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="somewhere.html">Sub Item 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Find nested `<ul>` elements, navigate to their parent `<li>`, select the `<a>` within that, and change the `href`.

```
$('li > ul').parent().children('a').attr('href', '#');
```

---

As for why your code doesn't work, that's due to two main issues. Firstly, [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) traverses all levels of descendants. What you are actually trying to do is just traverse first level descendants, so use [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children). Secondly, [`has`](http://api.jquery.com/has) (non-intuitively) doesn't return a bolean value, it simply filters the matched set to the necessary elements (so using it in an `if` is pointless, because any non-empty object evaluates to true). When corrected, your code would read:

```
$("#menu ul li").has("ul").children("a").attr("href", "#");
```

Either of these approaches will do what you need, but the second is more straightforward and so will probably yield better performance.

Comment: [***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/c4BnR/) - Note that the third method is from the accepted answer, and doesn't work. Instead of removing the `href` I simply highlight the link for visual effect.

Answer (score 1):

this will be fine: http://jsfiddle.net/H8JDy/

```
$('#menu ul li > ul').siblings('a').attr('href', '#'); // <---this does the trick
```

As commented by **nbrooks** *`there's no reason for it to be wrapped in the loop`*

Comment: That does work, but there's no reason for it to be wrapped in the loop. `$('li > ul').siblings('a').attr('href', '#');` is all you need.